# ARM program counter (PC) suddenly jumping out of code while executing `cmp` instruction

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, qemu

I am using the [GNU ARM Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads) and the [Unicorn Engine](https://www.unicorn-engine.org/) (basically a stripped-down QEMU) to try and analyze how some compiler optimized 32-bit ARM thumb code is being executed. But I'm facing a bizarre issue when running the code inside Unicorn/QEMU.

I am using a GCC cross-compiler targeting bare metal to compile C code to a thumb mode instructions ELF binary for an ARM Cortex M (ARM architecture v7-M). I use the following compiler flags:

- -Os: to optimize for small code size
- -flto: to enable link time optimization
- -ffunction-sections: to put every function into its own section in the output binary
- -fdata-sections: to put every static & global variable into its own section in the output binary
- --static: to make sure to have a fully statically linked binary
- --no-inline: to disable function inlining
- -fno-exceptions: to disable exception handling code generation

I am linking with [newlib-nano](https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-1.0) as an embedded libc. I also use linker argument --gc-sections to remove unused code and data at link time. I am compiling with semihosting enabled but have no breakpoints set. Finally, I use a linker script that makes sure the linker knows proper location and size of memory in which the binary can be loaded (though this is not really relevant as I load the binary into Unicorn/QEMU and map memory of my host system into QEMU as needed)

The problem is now that when my code hits a `cmp` instruction like `cmp r3, #0` the program counter jumps far away from the code instead of going on to the following branching instruction (it jumps from address 140 to 123172, instead of to 144 where I would expect it to and where the next branching instruction is). Subsequently I get a `UC_MEM_FETCH_INVALID` error from Unicorn as the CPU suddenly jumps into unmapped memory ... I can't imagine that an instruction like `cmp` triggers some kind of exception or interrupt, so I am at a loss of what is happening here. What could be the issue?

I'll gladly provide any info needed. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Every `cmp` instruction?  I notice you're not using `-mcpu=cortex-m3` or whatever or even `-mthumb`; are you sure the machine code is Thumb-mode?  Can you show disassembly (with hex machine code) for a [mcve]?  I wonder if perhaps ARM-mode machine code is getting executed by a CPU in thumb mode, making it decode as not the instructions you wanted.

Comment: Wait, yeah, `140` to `144` was your expected next PC?  Thumb mode `cmp r3, #0` is a 2-byte instruction, not 4.  (With machine code `2b00`, vs. the ARM encoding being `e3530000`.)

Comment: Could you provide your complete code or a [mcve] please?  It sure smells like you're accidentally in ARM mode.

Comment: Indeed, if I read correctly, `0000 e353` decodes in Thumb mode as `movs r0, r0 ; b pc+0x6a6` which would branch somewhere unexpected, though not quite the specific addresses which OP reports.

Comment: we need more info an example, being qemu you can give us something we can also run yes?

Comment: if nothing else a disassembly (not assembly, but disassembly) at and around the instruction in question.